# Selection sort best swapping case is not O(N) It is O(1) !!?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I seen in the selection sort if inner equals to minimum value it will be swapping them. but why you do it?
I just added the if statement for swapping if $inner = $min so why swapping them because they are the same index!. So why you do it?!!

The condition is : if $inner = $minimum (Don't swap). else they are not euqal (swap).

this is the code.

```
<?php
$a = array(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1);
$num = sizeof($a);

$comp = 0;
$swap = 0;

for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) { 
   echo "$a[$i] | ";
}
 echo "<br>";

for ($in=0; $in < $num; $in++) { 
      $min  = $in;
     for ($i=$in+1; $i < $num; $i++) { 
         if ($a[$i] < $a[$min]) {
           $min = $i;
         }
         $comp++;
     }
     if ($in != $min) {
       $past = $a[$min];
       $a[$min] = $a[$in];
       $a[$in] = $past;
       $swap++;
     }
}


for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) { 
   echo "$a[$i] | ";
}
echo "<br> comp : $comp , swap : $swap";


?>
```

Comment: Adding an `if` statement doesn't result in a change of best case complexity, it just shifts the work needed on every iteration to the boolean expression of the `if` statement. The inner `for` loop still dominates in complexity over the `if` statement.

Comment: Nothing to answer your question but : 1. Why do you use $min instead of $in in your second for loop ? 2. Did you know you can swap 2 values without using a third variable ? `$a = 1; $b = 2; $a = $a ^ $b; $b = $a ^ $b; $a = $a ^ $b;` does the job

Comment: Because i need to compare all items which is minimum (smallest). so the min variable it is used for that. and my problem is with a first min value...

Answer (score 0):

No. Time complexity doesn't depend upon number of swaps you did but on number of iterations for checking.

Lets take an example.,
1 4 9 3 0 8 5

You're saying that you'll iterate the whole array and find the lowest(minimum) number and you'll swap it with current index if both are not equal.

That means,

Your sorted array: 0 4 9 3 1 8 5

But it's not sorted. It means it is sorted upto 0th [1st number] index only.

You've to repeat it the same from 2nd index.

Now, lets find out the actual time complexity.

As you iterate for every index (let's take as 'i'), it is O(N) for outer loop and you'll iterate inner loop from i+1 (let's take as 'j') and it's O(N) for inner loop.

So O(N)*O(N)=O(N^2)

If you still have any doubt, lets take iterations of j that is,

for i=0, j iterates from 1 -> N

for i=1, j iterates from 2 -> N

for i=2, j iterates from 3 -> N  and so on...

so = (N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + (N-4) ......+ 1

=> (N (N-1)) / 2

= O(N^2)

Comment: No, my sorting are not wrong. I checked 1 4 9 3 0 8 5. the sort is 0 1 3 4 5 8 9 . I am just talking about swaping times not comparisons times. Thanks

Comment: You may consider anything but time complexity will be depend upon number of comparisons only.